# Jpa Hibernate c3po. Is connection broken or not?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, connection, c3p0

Please help me. I'm confused with c3po. In my applicatin i'm using hibernate (as JPA provider) and c3po. If in process transaction connection falls i'm must make some action.  When connection broken i'm catch a

```
   (javax.persistence.PersistenceException) javax.persistence.PersistenceException    
    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException:   
    Exception input/output: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
```

Q: Can I be sure that an GenericJDBCException only in the case when there is a break connections are those (problems connecting to the database (restart, network problems, kill session etc))?
In other words, I need to know is guaranteed that the exception is due to the connection falls.
Alexey.

my config

```
<property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>                    
                <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
                <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect"/>           
                <property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class" value="org.hibernate.service.jdbc.connections.internal.C3P0ConnectionProvider"/>
                <property name="hibernate.connection.autoReconnect" value="true"/>
                <!--максимальное количество соединений в пуле--> 
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="5"/>
                <!--минимальный размер пула--> 
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="1"/>
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment" value="1"/>
                <!--как долго ждать, чтобы подтвердить соединение, т.е. не закрывать его, а, например, сделать запрос "select 1"--> 
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="30"/><!-- In seconds -->  
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50"/>
                <!--таймаут для с3p0--> 
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="0"/>
                <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="false"/>
                <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50"/>
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.checkoutTimeout" value="0"/>
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery" value="select 1 from dual"/>
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout" value="true"/>
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckIn" value="true"/>
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryAttempts" value="0"/>
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquireRetryDelay" value="5000"/>
                <property name="hibernate.c3p0.breakAfterAcquireFailure" value="false"/>
```

Comment: hi, Connection reset by peer usually does mean a broken Connection. have you configured any form of c3p0 Connection testing (as Kanhu begins to suggest below)? please see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

Answer (score 0):

In your database configuration file(ex.hibernate.cfg.xml) just add below line

> `<property name="preferredTestQuery" value="SELECT 1"/>`

Please check this link to your reference http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#preferredTestQuery

If i am not reaching to your issue kindly post your configuration file also. so that i can give some accurate suggestion

Thank u

Comment: Thank you @Kanhu for responce. I'm edit my post and add config. I want to catch an exception in the case at the time of the transaction were problems connecting to the database. And just to separate the connection error from others which may (if it can) throws GenericJDBCException ....